# How to fix recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function which takes an integer as its parameter and returns the number of pairs of numbers within the integer that sum to 10. For example, findPairs(28164730) would return 3 because 2+8=10, 6+4=10, and 7+3=10.
This is what my code looks like now:

```
def find(x):
    x = str(x)
    count = 0
    if str((10 - int(x[0]))) in x:
        count = count + 1
        x = x[1:]
        find(x)
    elif len(x) > 1:
        x = x[1:]
        find(x)
    return count
```

The problem I am having is that the function will always return that the count is 1 because I am calling it again for recursion and it is setting the count back to 0 instead of just adding 1 to the count every time a pair is found. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What about `555`? Would you count `(5,5)` as a single pair or as three different pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your code isn't using the returned value of the recursive `find` call; it's just calling `find(x)`. This will fix your problem:

```
def find(x):
    x = str(x)
    count = 0
    if str((10 - int(x[0]))) in x:
        # count = count + 1
        x = x[1:]
        count = 1 + find(x)
    elif len(x) > 1:
        x = x[1:]
        count = find(x)
    return count
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to simplify by e.g. not using recursion at all. See e.g. the following attempt:

```
def find(x):
    x = str(x)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(x)-1):

        if str((10-int(x[i]))) in x[i+1:]:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Perhaps `ctr = {int(d): c for d, c in Counter(x).items()}` and `return sum(ctr[i] * ctr.get(k-i,0) for i in ctr) // 2` for `O(N)`?

Comment: Thanks for that but I am trying to practice recursion by going through some of these practice problems, appreciate the help tho!

Answer (score -1):

Either have a separate function that declares `count` then calls `find()`, or set `count` as a global variable. I think the first method is preferable.

```
def get_count(x):
  count = 0
  find(str(x))
  return count
```

Or something like that. Also if you use that method, make sure to remove the `count = 0` from the original `find` function

Comment: A global _variable_ is usually [a bad idea](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: Yep, that's why I said the first method is preferable.